# How can I install Internet explorer on Ubuntu?

Tags: internet-explorer, ubuntu, cross-browser

I need to test my website for internet explorer compatibility. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I have tried using wine but its not running (Wine asks me for installation steps but not installs it, it does not give any error too.)

Is there any other simple way to install it on Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Rather than installing locally, consider using BrowserStack http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft has created some customized Windows VHDs with the purpose of allowing web designers to test websites in Internet Explorer 10, 9, 8 and 7, for Free for 30 days:

You can download the virtual machine images from this website:

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Comment: hey Atul, i checked that too. It gives to much downloadables list. I am looking for other easy way like wine...

Comment: there is no "easy" with internet explorer. wine and visualization are the two possible routes, and i would suggest to go the route suggested by Atul, as it is somewhat official. you can also create a vm and install windows in there, if you happen to have some spare licences.

Comment: Trust me its more easier and reliable than WINE :). are you facing any problem in using this?

Comment: Thanks for response.. There was too much to download, so the problem is just bandwidth. Anyways i think have to do in same way only.

Comment: Given link is not working. 404

Answer (score 5):

This helped me to install IE

http://webnans.blogspot.in/2012/06/ie6-on-ubuntu.html

> Update your PlayonLinux  in Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install playonlinux
> ```
>
> Now Wine will get automatically updated,
>
> Open PlayonLinux and install IE6/IE7/IE8

Comment: your link could go dead anytime, you should probably give a summary of that article in your answer here.

Comment: what are further steps after getting playonlinux with above command, how can i reach to get IE on ubuntu